# Django - How to redirect after login to the same page?

Tags: python, django, facebook, registration

My login page is set in `/` `http://127.0.0.1:8000/`  but i want after login redirect to the same page `http://127.0.0.1:8000/` not `http://127.0.0.1:8000/home`, like Facebook login.
How could make this possible?.

Answer (score 0):

You should share your views.py code.
anyway you can use `HttpResponseRedirect`
Example :

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
def index(request):
    # you logic to check login
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')    # it will redirect you to  "/"
```